# String to associative array

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm having trouble using `preg_match_all` to split a string into key value pairs. An example of my string:

> "%Title:Movie%Sortable%Writer:%Indexed:false%"

Where I expect results like:

```
$result['Title'] = 'Movie';
$result['Sortable'] = '';
$result['Writer'] = '';
$result['Indexed'] = 'false';
```

I can split the string using `preg_match('/%/',$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` but it returns an indexed array. I need an associative array so that order is not important and I can use the key in a `switch` statement. What would be the correct regex to use in `preg_match_all`?

Comment: explode on "%" then loop though the resaults and explode on ":"

Comment: @Dagon Thanks. Maybe I was thinking a little too much with the regex matching. It's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
$input  = "%Title:Movie%Sortable%Writer:%Indexed:false%";
$output = array();

$data = explode('%', $input);
foreach ($data as $item) {
  list($key, $value) = explode(':', $item);
  $output[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: The only change I made was to replace `explode` with `preg_split` using the `NO_EMPTY` flag.

Comment: @Waldermort Using non-regex solution is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$string = "%Title:Movie%Sortable%Writer:%Indexed:false%";
$d = explode('%', $string);

foreach($d as $item){
   list($key,$value) = explode(':', $item);
   $arr[$key] = $value;

}

print_r($arr);
?>
```